# Pyinstaller exe not working on some PCs (LookupError: unknown encoding: cp65001)

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, pyinstaller

An executable that is compiled using Pyinstaller (3.5.dev0+0ffa574bf) crashes on execution on some PCs (works on others). Windows 10 pro.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "*******.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\sashako\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-tzzt7n\PyInstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 395, in load_module
  File "site-packages\pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\sashako\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-tzzt7n\PyInstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 395, in load_module
  File "site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1131, in <module>
  File "site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 975, in rc_params
  File "site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1100, in rc_params_from_file
  File "site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1018, in _rc_params_in_file
  File "contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
  File "site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1003, in _open_file_or_url
LookupError: unknown encoding: cp65001
[6292] Failed to execute script *******
```

Tried converting to cp65001 in the same cmd window (and power shell) before executing the script using chcp 65001. Tried other encodings as well.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading Pyinstaller has fixed the problem for me. `pip install pyinstaller==3.1`

Comment: 3.1 did not solve the problem, neither did 4.0. However, 3.6 worked